# user still can login although password and username is wrong

Tags: php, android, mysqli, ionic-framework

this problem make me confuse why user still can login although username and password is wrong. I don't have any idea in this problem. i try build android with ionic framework
this my controller
**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, kaka, $ionicPopup, $state, Varlogin) {
            $scope.loginData = {};
            $scope.proseslogin = function () {
                kaka.loginUser($scope.loginData.username, $scope.loginData.password).success(function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                            Varlogin.setObject(data[0]);
                            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Selamat Datang',
                            template: 'Perikasa keadaan motor anda!'
                             });
                            $state.go('app.home');
                    } else {
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Login Gagal!',
                            template: 'Periksa Username dan Password anda!'
                        });
                    }
                }).error(function (data) {
                });
            };
            $scope.register = function () {
                $state.go('register');
            };

        })
```

**
and this my php 
**

```
if($function == "login" ){
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "select * from login where username='$w5'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $pass = $row['hash_password'];
    $hash_password = password_verify($w6, $pass);

    if($hash_password == TRUE) {
    $sqlcode = $con->query("select * from login where username='$w5' AND hash_password='$pash' AND aktif='Y'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    $jsonObj = array();
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlcode)) {
        $jsonObj[] = $result;
        echo "Berhasil";
         }
    }else {
    echo "gagal";
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

**
please help my problem

Comment: Just put `AND aktif='Y'` in the first query. Also what are `$w5` and `w6`? You should parameterize the `$w5`. Also why check the return length and not the actual value? You should isolate the issue. Is the PHP returning the correct value? There are many things here I think you should correct.

Comment: Think about what you have put as a condition  for a successful login in the JavaScript code. Should be obvious why this is happening.

Comment: w5 and w6 is paramater from username and password, and i dont have a idea where is the problem

Comment: Please read everything I wrote. There are multiple issues here you need to correct.